# what is "Use Custom Permissions" in Magento installer?

Tags: magento

What is meaning of "Use Custom Permissions" check-box in Magento installer? version 1.7.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a downloader mode wherein it will allow you to proceed with custom permissions. You can set this in `config.ini` as `mkdir_mode` and `chmod_file_mode`. e.g:

```
mkdir_mode=0777
chmod_mode=0666
```

The above values are the defaults.

the following snippet found in Magento CE Downloader file `./downloader/Maged/Model/Config.php` specifies the possible config values:

```
$configParams = array(
    'protocol',
    'preferred_state',
    'use_custom_permissions_mode',
    'mkdir_mode',
    'chmod_file_mode',
    'magento_root',
    'downloader_path',
    'root_channel_uri',
    'root_channel',
    'ftp',
);
```

As you can see, `root_channel` is there and if you open the `config.ini` file, you should see it already set to `community` or according to your magento installation type can be `pro`, `enterprise` AFAIK

Just set it to `No` to experience the best results.